# How to create a matrix from all possible combinations of 2 or more matrices?

Tags: r, matrix, combinations, combinatorics

Let's say, there are two matrices:

```
A <- B <- diag(3)  
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1
```

I want to create a new matrix AB, which consists of all the possible combinations of rows of A and B. Expected result:

```
> AB
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    0    0    1    0    0
 [2,]    1    0    0    0    1    0
 [3,]    1    0    0    0    0    1
 [4,]    0    1    0    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    1    0    0    1    0
 [6,]    0    1    0    0    0    1
 [7,]    0    0    1    1    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    1    0    1    0
 [9,]    0    0    1    0    0    1
```

How to do this efficiently? And can it be extended for more than two matrices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `expand.grid()` and take its output to index the matrix A and B,

```
x <- expand.grid(1:3,1:3)

cbind(A[x[,1],], B[x[,2],])
```

gives,

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    0    0    1    0    0
 [2,]    0    1    0    0    1    0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    1
 [4,]    1    0    0    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    1    0    0    1    0
 [6,]    0    0    1    0    0    1
 [7,]    1    0    0    1    0    0
 [8,]    0    1    0    0    1    0
 [9,]    0    0    1    0    0    1
```

**EDIT:**

For more than two matrices, you can use a function like below,

```
myfun <- function(...) {

     arguments <- list(...)

     a <- expand.grid(lapply(arguments, function(x) 1:nrow(x)))
    
    
     do.call(cbind,lapply(seq(a),function(x) { arguments[[x]][a[,x],] }))

 
}

out <- myfun(A,B,C)

head(out)
```

gives,

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0     0
[2,]    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0     0
[3,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    0    0     0
[4,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0     0
[5,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    0     0
[6,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0     0
```

**Data:**

```
A <- B <- diag(3)
C <- diag(4)
```

Comment: This is acceptable when there are 2 matrices. How can I generalize it for more than 2 matrices?

Comment: Seems perfect. Thanks

Comment: It works quite well for a maximum of 15 matrices in my computer before running into a memory problem. Unfortunately, I need it for a minimum of 18 matrices. Can you suggest any way around it that can be worth trying? Thanks

Comment: I am not so sure. Maybe `data.table::CJ` can be more memory efficient instead of  `expand.grid() `. There is also another package   `ffbase ` which has  `expand.ffgrid() ` function. But again, I can not be so sure about the memory issues. You may want to ask it in another question by referring this one.