# Drawing conditional combinations of a binary vector one by one

Tags: r, matrix, conditional-statements, sparse-matrix, combinatorics

I am trying to write a routine to find combinations conditionally of a binary vector. For example, consider the following vector:

```
> A <- rep(c(1,0,0),3)
> A
[1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

Note that, length of the vector A is always multiple of 3. So the following condition always holds:

```
length(A) %% 3 == 0
```

The main condition is that there must be only a single 1 in each set of 3 vectors consecutively. In this example, for instance, one element of A[1:3] will be 1, one element of A[4:6] will be 1 and one element of A[7:9] will be 1 and the rest are all 0. Therefore, for this example, there will be a total of 27 possible combinations.

**Objective** is to make a routine to draw/return the next valid combination until all the possible legal combinations are returned.

**Note** that, I am not looking for a table with all the possible combinations. That [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356711/how-to-create-a-matrix-from-all-possible-combinations-of-2-or-more-matrices) is already available in my other query in StackOverflow. However, with that method, I am running into memory problems when going beyond more than a length of 45 elements in A, as it is returning the full matrix which is huge. Therefore instead of storing the full matrix, I want to retrieve one combination at a time, and then decide later if I want to store it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the OP is after is an iterator. If we were to do this properly, we would write a class in `C++` with a `get_next` method, and expose this to `R`. As it stands, with base R, since everything is passed by value, we must call a function on our object-to-be-updated and reassign the object-to-be-updated every time.

Here is a very crude implementation:

```
get_next <- function(comb, v, m) {
    s <- seq(1L, length(comb), length(v))
    e <- seq(length(v), length(comb), length(v))
    
    last_comb <- rev(v)
    can_be_incr <- sapply(seq_len(m), function(x) {
        !identical(comb[s[x]:e[x]], last_comb)
    })

    if (all(!can_be_incr)) {
        return(FALSE)
    } else {
        idx  <- which(can_be_incr)[1L]
        span <- s[idx]:e[idx]
        j <- which(comb[span] == 1L)
        comb[span[j]] <- 0L
        comb[span[j + 1L]] <- 1L
        
        if (idx > 1L) {
            ## Reset previous maxed out sections
            for (i in 1:(idx - 1L)) {
                comb[s[i]:e[i]] <- v
            }
        }
    }
    
    return(comb)
}
```

And here is a simple usage:

```
m <- 3L
v <- as.integer(c(1,0,0))
comb <- rep(v, m)
count <- 1L

while (!is.logical(comb)) {
    cat(count, ": ", comb, "\n")
    comb <- get_next(comb, v, m)
    count <- count + 1L
}

1 :  1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
2 :  0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
3 :  0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 
4 :  1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
5 :  0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
6 :  0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 
7 :  1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
8 :  0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
9 :  0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
10 :  1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 
11 :  0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 
12 :  0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 
13 :  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 
14 :  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 
15 :  0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 
16 :  1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 
17 :  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 
18 :  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 
19 :  1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 
20 :  0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 
21 :  0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 
22 :  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
23 :  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
24 :  0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 
25 :  1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 
26 :  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 
27 :  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Note, this implementation will be memory efficient, however it will be very slow.

Comment: I took some time to reply as I was trying to check with m = 18 as this is what I needed. Unfortunately, it's almost a day now but the computation is still going on. I was wondering if the function is written in C++ and utilize RCPP to run it in R. Would it substantially reduce the computation time?

Comment: @Rel_Ai, yes, writing this in `C++` would be a huge improvement. If I were doing it, I would add a feature to obtain multiple iterations at once. Something like `get_next(n = 1000)`, to get the next 1000 iterations. This would allow most of the computation to stay in `C++` before going back to the `R` world.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have much experience in C++ except for converting some simple R codes for using with Rcpp. Is there any similar C++ code chunk you can refer to or add it with your answer?

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could add it to your answer.